# LXD lose snapshot after creating containers from them, if using zfs

Tags: lxc, zfs, lxd

I am having issues when creating containers from snaphots, when using lxd with
zfs as backstorage.  I can create the container, but when I delete it, the
snapshot gets deleted at zfs level (not at lxd).

I am using lxd in Ubuntu 16.04, and the funny thing is that does not happen in
every box: some work fine, others never did, and others worked fine for a while
and then broke.

I wonder now if creating containers from snapshots is legit, or if operation
semantics are unspecified.

This can be seen in this example

```
$ lxc launch ubuntu:14.04 mycontainer  # Happens with other images
$ lxc stop mycontainer                 # stop is optional
$ lxc snapshot mycontainer mysnap0
$ lxc copy mycontainer/mysnap0 mycontainer1
$ lxc delete mycontainer1
$ lxc copy mycontainer/mysnap0 mycontainer2
error: rsync failed: rsync: change_dir "/var/lib/lxd/snapshots/mycontainer/mysnap0" failed: No such file or directory (2)
rsync error: some files/attrs were not transferred (see previous errors) (code 23) at main.c(1183) [sender=3.1.1]
```

But lxd still thinks the snapshot is good.

```
$ lxc info mycontainer
Name: mycontainer
Architecture: x86_64
Created: 2016/06/16 10:53 UTC
Status: Stopped
Type: persistent
Profiles: default
Snapshots:
  mysnap0 (taken at 2016/06/16 10:54 UTC) (stateless)
```

Another example that makes me think is lxd who request zfs to delete the snapshot:

```
$ lxc snapshot mycontainer mysnap1
$ lxc copy mycontainer/mysnap1 mycontainer2
$ lxc copy mycontainer/mysnap1 mycontainer3
$ lxc delete mycontainer2
error: Failed to destroy ZFS filesystem: cannot destroy 'debtool/containers/mycontainer@snapshot-mysnap1': snapshot has dependent clones
```

And some info on the versions I use:

```
zfs-zed                   0.6.5.6-0ubuntu8
zfsutils-linux            0.6.5.6-0ubuntu8
lxd                       2.0.2-0ubuntu1~16.04.1
lxd-client                2.0.2-0ubuntu1~16.04.1
lxd-tools                 2.0.2-0ubuntu1~16.04.1
liblxc1                   2.0.0-0ubuntu2
lxc                       2.0.0-0ubuntu2
lxc-common                2.0.0-0ubuntu2
lxc-templates             2.0.0-0ubuntu2
lxc1                      2.0.0-0ubuntu2
lxcfs                     2.0.0-0ubuntu2.1
```

Any ideas on how I could fix/troubleshoot the issue?